# Create SQL statement in PHP function using an Array

Tags: php, arrays

I am creating a PHP function that will take some values, one of which is an array, that I need to use in a MySQL query.

I am creating the array as follows:

```
 $newsArray = createArticleArray(array(2,20,3),5);
```

Then the function looks something like this (cut down for readability)

```
 function createArticleArray($sectionArray = array(1),$itemsToShow) 
 { 
 $SQL = "
  SELECT 
    *
  FROM
    tbl_section
  WHERE
    (tbl_section.fld_section_uid = 2 OR tbl_section.fld_section_uid = 20 OR tbl_section.fld_section_uid = 3)
  ORDER BY
    tbl_article.fld_date_created DESC LIMIT 0,$itemsToShow";
 }
```

The section `tbl_section.fld_section_uid = 2 OR tbl_section.fld_section_uid = 20 OR tbl_section.fld_section_uid = 3` is where I need to use the array values.

Basically I need to loop through the values in the array making up that part of the query, however I am having a little problem on how to show or not show the "OR" bits of it as there might be only 1 value or as many as I need.

I was thinking of something like this:

```
 foreach($sectionArray as $section)
 {
   $sqlString = $sqlString . "tbl_section.fld_section_uid = $section OR";
 }
```

but I don't know how to work out if to put the "OR" in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [implode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
$conditionParts = array(); 
foreach($sectionArray as $section){
   $conditionParts[] = "tbl_section.fld_section_uid = $section";
}
$sqlString .= implode(' OR ', $conditionParts);
```

This solution answers your question and show you how to use the `implode` function, but for your specific case you should really use the [IN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator.

```
$sqlString .= "tbl_section.fld_section_uid IN(".implode(',', $sectionArray).")";
```

Answer (score 1):

The query can be made simpler and easier to generate if you use [`WHERE <column> IN (value1,value2,...)`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) syntax.

Use PHP's [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to produce the `(value1,value2,...)` part:

```
$SQL .= ' WHERE tbl_section.fld_section_uid IN (' . implode(',', $array) . ') ';
```

Yields something like this:

```
SELECT
...
WHERE tbl_section.fld_section_uid IN (2,20,3)
...
```

Comment: You've missed a couple of parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to put an extraneous 0 at the end to consume the final "OR" without any effect. The query parser will just remove it: `A OR B OR C OR 0`  is turned into `A OR B OR C`.

Another solution is to use `implode` to insert the `OR`:

```
$sqlString = "tbl_section.fld_section = "
 . implode($sectionArray," OR tbl_section.fld_section_uid = ");
```

Of course, the correct solution is just to use `IN`:

```
"WHERE tbl_section.fld_section_uid IN(".implode($sectionArray,',').")";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function createArticleArray($sectionArray = array(), $itemsToShow) {
    $conditions = array();
    for ($i = 0, $s = count($sectionArray); $i < $s; ++$i) {
        $conditions[] = 'tbl_section.fld_section_uid = ' . (int) $sectionArray[$i];
    }
    $SQL = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_section WHERE ' . implode(' OR ', $conditions) . ' ORDER BY tbl_article.fld_date_created DESC LIMIT 0, ' . (int) $itemsToShow;
}
```

Comment: Those are conditions, not clauses. SELECT, FROM, WHERE are clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Use PDO's prepare method: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("
  SELECT 
    *
  FROM
    tbl_section
  WHERE
    (tbl_section.fld_section_uid = ? OR tbl_section.fld_section_uid = ? OR tbl_section.fld_section_uid = ?)
  ORDER BY
    tbl_article.fld_date_created DESC LIMIT 0,$itemsToShow");

$statement->execute( $sectionArray );
```